# batch edit keymap / shorcut to replace all the modifier key from 'cmd' to 'ctrl'

Tags: shortcut

Hi is there a way to batch replace all the 'cmd/oskey' key to 'ctrl' in the keymap ? i'm trying to bring keymap from mac/osx to windows and want all the hotkey to map for example from cmd-R to ctrl-R etc. is there a better way rather than manually edit them ?

Thanks.

Comment: Aren't all default hotkeys on OSX mapped to Cmd and Ctrl? If so, I'd go the other way around and just enable 'Cmd' since this key does not exist on a windows keyboard and will be ignored.

Comment: in my laptop , cmd key will be mapped to 'win' key, not to ctrl.  I need to switch between mac and osx and vice versa , and i need to preferences can be shared between the two where 'cmd' will be mapped to 'ctrl' ( or 'ctrl' to 'cmd' if i switch from win to osx) .

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out? Could you share the solution?